# How do I make my tkinter radiobuttons work properly?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing code which spawns a second window which has two radiobuttons. I'm trying to make it so that only one of them can be selected at any time, but it only lets me select them both and can't deselect after that.

```
def editWindow():
    
    itemChoice = tk.IntVar()
    
    editMenu = tk.Toplevel()
    editMenu.geometry('400x400')
    editMenu.resizable(False,False)
    editMenu['bg'] = 'black'
    editMenu.title('Configure Menu')
    
    head2 = tk.Label(editMenu,text = "Add Item:",font = ("Garamond",20),bg = 'black')
    head2.grid(column = 0,row = 0, sticky = 'N', pady = 10, padx = 20)
    itemChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=itemChoice,value = 1)
    dealChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=itemChoice,value = 2)
    itemChoice.grid(column = 0,row=1)
    dealChoice.grid(column = 1,row=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is caused because there are duplicate variable names:

```py
def editWindow():

itemChoice = tk.IntVar() #first delaration of itemChoice

editMenu = tk.Toplevel()
editMenu.geometry('400x400')
editMenu.resizable(False,False)
editMenu['bg'] = 'black'
editMenu.title('Configure Menu')

head2 = tk.Label(editMenu,text = "Add Item:",font = ("Garamond",20),bg = 'black')
head2.grid(column = 0,row = 0, sticky = 'N', pady = 10, padx = 20)
itemChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=itemChoice,value = 1) # usage and redeclaration 
dealChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=itemChoice,value = 2) # usage of the radiobutton `itemChoice`
itemChoice.grid(column = 0,row=1)
dealChoice.grid(column = 1,row=1)
```

after renaming one of these duplicates, your program should work correct.

your code after renaming the first occurence of itemChoice:

```py
def editWindow():

    item_choice_intvar = tk.IntVar() # renamed itemChoice to item_choice_intvar 

    editMenu = tk.Toplevel()
    editMenu.geometry('400x400')
    editMenu.resizable(False,False)
    editMenu['bg'] = 'black'
    editMenu.title('Configure Menu')

    head2 = tk.Label(editMenu,text = "Add Item:",font = ("Garamond",20),bg = 'black')
    head2.grid(column = 0,row = 0, sticky = 'N', pady = 10, padx = 20)
    itemChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=item_choice_intvar,value = 1) # usage of renamed var
    dealChoice = tk.Radiobutton(editMenu,text = 'Menu Item',variable=item_choice_intvar,value = 2) # usage of renamed var
    itemChoice.grid(column = 0,row=1)
    dealChoice.grid(column = 1,row=1)
```

(see comments for more explanation)

Comment: `item_choice` should be `item_choice_intvar` instead in `tk.Radiobutton(...)`

Comment: oops, you're right